# Constellation plotting

Tags: redhawksdr

I am looking at comparing the signal constellations before and after a processing stage.  Two questions:

Can the plotting module in the IDE be configured for plotting constellations?

Can two constellations be displayed side-by-side in the IDE?  I have two plots open, but I cannot seem to drag the plot tab to separate the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to plot constellations, though it may not be obvious how. First, ensure that the SRI for the output data has "mode" set to 1 to indicate complex data; otherwise, the data is assumed to be real.

There are two things you will want to do to view the BULKIO stream as symbols:

- Change real/imaginary mode to X/Y.
- Change plot mode from line to symbol.

To display each complex pair as an X/Y point, middle-click on the plot of interest and select "Mode > RvI". From the "Mode" menu you can also select various other ways of viewing complex data (magnitude, real only, imaginary only, phase, etc.).

To switch from lines to symbols:

1. Middle-click on the plot again and select "Layers." A new menu titled "Legend" should pop up.
2. Look for a layer with a name like "_UNIQUE_PIPE13" and left click on the line sample (it should look like a rainbow by default). This will pop up the layer configuration menu.
3. Click on "Line" and toggle the "Symbol" checkbox.
4. Click on the layer again. Select "Line" and uncheck the "Solid" checkbox.

You can change other aspects of the layer as well, such as the line type, symbol type and color.

As for placing two plots side-by-side, the plots have to be on different plot views (by default, the plots are all placed on the same view). You can open a new tab by clicking on the triangle on the upper right of the "Port Data" tab and selecting "New Plot View". From there, you can detach the tab into another window or move it to a different section of the IDE.